# How do I make firebase to get a name from edit text?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading an image to firebase storage. It gets a randomly generated name. How do I make the name come from edit text field? Is it possible to do that?

```
 StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

Comment: Please be more clear to what you're saying because the question appears too vague.

Comment: I am uploading an image to firebase storage. It gets a randomly generated name. How do I make the name come from edit text field?

Comment: You're getting a random UID yourself, just set your line in `.child()` as follows:
`"images/+yourEditText.getText().toString()"`

Comment: Is this what you were looking for, if not be more clear and I will write you an answer that might help :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. I am new to this kind of stuff so I don't know all the attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically set the name of the image you store in Firebase storage according to you. For example if you have an EditText with variable name as `editText`.

You can get text from the `editText` and set it as the name of your image, like following:

```java
StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ editText.getText().toString());
```

You use `editText.getText()` to get the text of the `editText`.